# HTML autocomplete - input name is array

Tags: html

I have similar input:
< input name="field[14][x]" type="text">

Autocomplete no work, I tested Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome. I need latest text what I complete to the this field.

Thanks for solutions.

Comment: That's not even a question

Comment: You can make a datalist and attach the list to your input. Can you be more specific on your question? Something like this: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp

Comment: In your solution I must before make list of "autocomplete" but I need history of this filed. I mean what I before insert to this fileld