# How to use browser autocomplete when input name contains an array?

Tags: html, forms, input

I have a form with several input fields with the same name and an array value. For instance:

```
<input type="text" name="customer_reference[1]">
<input type="text" name="customer_reference[2]">
<input type="text" name="customer_reference[3]">
```

I would like to use the browser auto complete function. This function uses the name tag. Therefore I have different auto complete suggestions for `customer_reference[1]` then for `customer_reference[2]`.

Is there a way to let the browser threat the fields as being the same? So when the user starts to type in a reference, the browser will give the same suggestions in all fields with the same name, but a different array value?

I tried using, but no difference:

```
<input type="text" name="customer_reference[1]" autocomplete="customer_reference">
<input type="text" name="customer_reference[2]" autocomplete="customer_reference">
<input type="text" name="customer_reference[3]" autocomplete="customer_reference">
```

I also tried setting an additional id or class, but the browser does not seem to use this.
And I also tried using a label.

Is there any way to let the browser auto complete function know that the fields are of the same 'type of data', so it will give the same suggestions?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45736583/html-autocomplete-input-name-is-array

Answer (score 0):

You can use datalist tag.Since the datalist  tag is used to provide an "autocomplete" feature on input elements.

For eg:

```
 <input list="browsers" name="browser">
  <datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">
    <option value="Firefox">
  </datalist>
```

Comment: But then I would have to keep track of the user input and place it in a datalist myself. I would rather let the browser keep track of the input history.

Comment: Sorry.I didn't get you